# How to access associated object id in ajax loaded form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using Rails 3.2, how can I access the id of an associated object within an embedded form loaded by ajax?

For example, I have an object called Hotels. Each Hotel has_many Rooms. When I edit a Hotel I would like to add new Rooms to this Hotel using an ajax loaded new Rooms form on the Hotel edit page.

I started by creating all the ajax using jquery on the Rooms index page. Everything works great there, but I don't have a Hotel ID, so I present a Hotel selection dropdown box. Now, I would like to add a new Room directly on the Hotel edit page. I don't understand how to pass the Hotel ID (@hotel.id) to the new ajax loaded Room _form.html.erb partial. On the _form.html.erb partial, I have:

```
  <% if defined?(@hotel.id) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :hotel_id, :value => @hotel.id %>                    
  <% else %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:hotel_id, Hotel.all, :id, :name) %>
  <% end %>
```

On the Hotel edit page, I have a link to add a new Room:

```
  <%= link_to 'Add a Room', new_room_path, :remote=>true, :class => 'new_room' %>
```

And in my rooms_controller.rb I have:

```
  # GET /rooms/new
  # GET /rooms/new.json
  def new
    @room = Room.new

    render :partial => 'form', :locals => { :room => @room }
  end
```

How can I get the associated @hotel.id inside my ajax loaded new Room _form.html.erb partial?

Comment: I would suggest you to pass the hotel_id in the `new_room_path` as a parameter.

Comment: Can give an example of how to do this?

Comment: Just configure your `routes.rb` file to accept a parameter adding an `/:hotel_id` for example. Then you could access that in your controller by `hotel_id = params[:hotel_id]`. Something like that.